# How to force stop SWI-prolog during query on MacOS

Tags: swi-prolog

Is there a way to force stop SWI-Prolog during a query? E.g., say I have a predicate (`bad_foo(X)`) that goes into an infinite loop. When I query this predicate in SWI-Prolog the query runs for a while (sometimes a few minutes) and then fails with `ERROR: Out of local stack`:

```
?- bad_foo(1).
(% and after a long wait...)
ERROR: Out of local stack
```

My question: How can I skip the wait and stop the query before it runs out of stack? In short, I'm looking for the equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> from Linux.

I'm using SWI-Prolog version 7.6.4 on MacOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> doesn't work but pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> suspends the query and prompts a help message which can then be used to abort the query by typing <kbd>a</kbd> for abort:

```
?- bad_foo(1).
(% press Cmd+C and you'll be prompted:)
Action (h for help) ?
(% press a to abort)
abort
?-
```